# Web Service Serialization produces an unwanted root in SOAP body

Tags: web-services, serialization, soap

History:

A WSDL was provided to me with which I generated a service reference.
The object to serialize and send to the web service to consume, was a strongly, complex-typed class.

Instead of sending a strongly, complex-typed class, I wanted to send an XMLDocument instead.

So I modified the service and I am left with this:

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("wsdl", "4.0.30319.17929")]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Web.Services.WebServiceBindingAttribute(Name =    "B2MML_ProcessProductionPerformance_MaterialConsumption_OBBinding", Namespace="http://company.com/M2D/Manufacturing/ManufacturingExecution/GoodsIssue/pi")]
public partial class B2MML_ProcessProductionPerformance_MaterialConsumption_OBService : System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol {

private System.Threading.SendOrPostCallback B2MML_ProcessProductionPerformance_MaterialConsumption_OBOperationCompleted;

public B2MML_ProcessProductionPerformance_MaterialConsumption_OBService() 
{
}

public event B2MML_ProcessProductionPerformance_MaterialConsumption_OBCompletedEventHandler B2MML_ProcessProductionPerformance_MaterialConsumption_OBCompleted;

[System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapDocumentMethodAttribute("http://sap.com/xi/WebService/soap1.1", OneWay=true, Use=System.Web.Services.Description.SoapBindingUse.Literal, ParameterStyle=System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapParameterStyle.Bare)]
public void B2MML_ProcessProductionPerformance_MaterialConsumption_OB(XmlDocument ProcessProductionPerformance)
{
    this.Invoke("B2MML_ProcessProductionPerformance_MaterialConsumption_OB", new object[] {
               ProcessProductionPerformance});
}

public System.IAsyncResult BeginB2MML_ProcessProductionPerformance_MaterialConsumption_OB(XmlDocument ProcessProductionPerformance, System.AsyncCallback callback, object asyncState)
{
    return this.BeginInvoke("B2MML_ProcessProductionPerformance_MaterialConsumption_OB", new object[] {
                ProcessProductionPerformance}, callback, asyncState);
}

public void EndB2MML_ProcessProductionPerformance_MaterialConsumption_OB(System.IAsyncResult asyncResult)
{
    this.EndInvoke(asyncResult);
}

public void B2MML_ProcessProductionPerformance_MaterialConsumption_OBAsync(XmlDocument ProcessProductionPerformance)
{
    this.B2MML_ProcessProductionPerformance_MaterialConsumption_OBAsync(ProcessProductionPerformance, null);
}

public void B2MML_ProcessProductionPerformance_MaterialConsumption_OBAsync(XmlDocument ProcessProductionPerformance, object userState)
{
    if ((this.B2MML_ProcessProductionPerformance_MaterialConsumption_OBOperationCompleted == null))
    {
        this.B2MML_ProcessProductionPerformance_MaterialConsumption_OBOperationCompleted = new System.Threading.SendOrPostCallback(this.OnB2MML_ProcessProductionPerformance_MaterialConsumption_OBOperationCompleted);
    }
    this.InvokeAsync("B2MML_ProcessProductionPerformance_MaterialConsumption_OB", new object[] {
                ProcessProductionPerformance}, this.B2MML_ProcessProductionPerformance_MaterialConsumption_OBOperationCompleted, userState);
}

private void OnB2MML_ProcessProductionPerformance_MaterialConsumption_OBOperationCompleted(object arg)
{
    if ((this.B2MML_ProcessProductionPerformance_MaterialConsumption_OBCompleted != null))
    {
        System.Web.Services.Protocols.InvokeCompletedEventArgs invokeArgs = ((System.Web.Services.Protocols.InvokeCompletedEventArgs)(arg));
        this.B2MML_ProcessProductionPerformance_MaterialConsumption_OBCompleted(this, new System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs(invokeArgs.Error, invokeArgs.Cancelled, invokeArgs.UserState));
    }
}

public new void CancelAsync(object userState) 
{
    base.CancelAsync(userState);
}
}

[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("wsdl", "4.0.30319.17929")]
public delegate void       B2MML_ProcessProductionPerformance_MaterialConsumption_OBCompletedEventHandler(object sender, System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs e);
```

Problem Decription:

I am able to send an XMLDocument successfully, however, if my XMLDocument looks like this:

```
<ProcessProductionPerformance xmlns="SomeNS">
  <ApplicationArea>Some data here</ApplicationArea>
  <DataArea>Some data there</DataArea>
</ProcessProductionPerformance>
```

I am seeing the below in the SOAP Body (seen via Fiddler):

```
<ProcessProductionPerformance>
   <ProcessProductionPerformance xmlns="SomeNS">
      <ApplicationArea>Some data here</ApplicationArea>
      <DataArea>Some data there</DataArea>
   </ProcessProductionPerformance>
</ProcessProductionPerformance>
```

Information:

1) I do not have access to modify the web service

2) I've tried to pack XMLDocument ApplicationArea and XMLDocument DataArea individually into a class and try to serialize the class, I end up with this in the SOAP Body:

```
<ProcessProductionPerformance xmlns="SomeNS">
   <ApplicationArea>
      <ApplicationArea xmlns="SomeNS">Some data here</ApplicationArea>
   <ApplicationArea>
   <DataArea>
      <DataArea xmlns="SomeNS">Some data there</DataArea>
   <DataArea>
</ProcessProductionPerformance>
```

3) I suspect it's to do with the SOAPBindingUse or SOAPBindingStyle perhaps? I did not change this at all because I don't know much about it.

4) I'm just a kid new to C#.. Please have mercy.

**EDIT:**

Okay it seems that the enums SoapBindingUse.Literal and SoapParameterStyle.Bare have a major role to play in this. But I'm still stuck because my use of this has been correct all along.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/2b4bx2t6%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

So what am I missing?

By the way, not sure if you humans care about the client but I'm calling the service like this:

```
var processProductionPerformance = new XmlDocument();
processProductionPerformance.LoadXml(@xmlText);
var sendPerformanceToSap = new B2MML_ProcessProductionPerformance_MaterialConsumption_OBService
            {
                    //Url = Link here,
                    //Credentials since
            };
sendPerformanceToSap.B2MML_ProcessProductionPerformance_MaterialConsumption_OBAsync(processProductionPerformance);
```